# WordPress Multiple Loops

Tags: wordpress, loops

I am getting horribly frustrated trying to build multiple loops in WordPress. I've looked at loads of articles - what am I doing wrong. I placed the following in the loop.php file (because I've built the homepage on this)...

```
<!--Loop 1-->
<?php global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'category_name=news&posts_per_page=3');?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!--Loop 2-->
<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
<?php global $query_string2; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string2.'category_name=jobs&posts_per_page=3');?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Incidentally if I take away Loop 2 it works, seems like it doesn't like 2 loops on the page - even though I've used reset_query

Comment: try new [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) instant of query_posts

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

  // your output html   

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

You have nested the loops (missing endwhile).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just invent a variable "query_string2" and expect it to work ;)

Try this:

```
<!--Loop 1-->
<?php
global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'category_name=news&posts_per_page=3');?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!--Loop 2-->
<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
<?php 
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'category_name=jobs&posts_per_page=3');?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

If that doesn't work (I don't remember whether `wp_reset_query()` resets the `$query_string` global off the top of my head), try the following:

```
<?php
global $query_string; // required
$query_string_backup = $query_string;
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'category_name=news&posts_per_page=3');?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<!--Loop 2-->
<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
<?php 
$posts = query_posts($query_string_backup.'category_name=jobs&posts_per_page=3');?>

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but none of them work unfortunately :-(

Comment: I suppose you looked into the `endwhile` issue as well, did you?

Comment: Putting an end while after each one like this http://pastebin.com/riKHR7Xh ? I've tried that, still no luck - it's just blank.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
<?php
    global $query_string;        //make sure these are in the correct format for post queries
    global $query_string1;

    // First loop
    $first_loop = new WP_Query( $query_string.'category_name=news&posts_per_page=3');

    while ( $first_loop->have_posts() ) : $first_loop->the_post() :
        // do your thing
        // e.g: $first_loop->the_content();
    endwhile;


    // second loop
    $second_loop = new WP_Query( $query_string1.'category_name=news&posts_per_page=3');

    while ( $second_loop->have_posts() ) : $second_loop->the_post() :
        //do your thing
    endwhile;

    // Reset Post Data 
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

Comment: Just tried this http://pastebin.com/Asnz9gLx - sorry but it didn't work, still blank page.

Comment: What exactly is inside your $query_string variables? The above code will work without those variables inside the WP_Query argument.

Answer (score 0):

I could help out, but I think that first, I should understand 1 fundamental: WHAT are you trying to do exactly? What is your goal? Why do you think you need nested loops?

This will help me aswering more correctly.

Comment: Thanks very much for your offer, I've managed to solve it now with a friend's help. Will post answer now.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following code, which I put in a page template (my friend advised that it's best leaving the loop.php alone)

```
<?php $custom_query = new WP_Query('category_name=news'); // only News category
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); // reset the query ?>

<?php $custom_query = new WP_Query('category_name=jobs'); // only Jobs category
while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?>

<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a function called rewind_posts() that rewinds the loop posts in order to let you re-use the same query in different locations on the same page

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/rewind_posts